# CSV parsing for embedded double quotes

Tags: c++, algorithm, parsing, csv

I've written a simple CSV file parser. But after looking at the [wiki page on CSV formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) I noticed some "extensions" to the basic format. Specifically embedded comma via double quotes. I've managed to parse those, however there is a second issue: embedded double quotes.

Example:

12345,"ABC, ""IJK"" XYZ"  -> [1234] and [ABC, "IJK" XYZ]

I can't seem to find the correct way to distinguish between an enclosed double quote and none. So my question is what is the correct way/algorithm to parse CVS formats such as the one above?

Comment: It looks like the quote characters are represented in your CSV file by two quote charactes in a row. This is similar to the way SQL databases often quote their single-quote characters, and is used in other contexts as well. Is your question about this quoting method, or are you asking how to modify your *code* to handle this? We'll probably need to see some of your code.

Comment: Can you show us some of your code? There are many ways to solve this problem, but I think showing all of them would be overkill. If you can give us a hint to your current approach we can direct our answer to fit with what you're already doing.

Comment: @Zenikoder: I've explained further in an answer below.

Comment: Don't forget embedded end of line characters. Most people do and build incorrect parsers (even popular commercial applications out there right now).

Answer (score 5):

The way I normally think about this is basically to look at the quoted value as a single, unquoted value *or* a sequence of double quoted values that form a value joined by quotes.  That is,

- to parse the next atom in the row:

  - read up to the first non whitespace character
  - if the current character is not a quote:

    - mark the current spot
    - read up to the next comma or newline
    - return the text between the mark and the character before the comma (strip spaces if appropriate)
  - if the current character is a quote:

    - create an empty string buffer
    - while the current character is *not* a quote

      - mark the current position +1 (skip the quote character)
      - read up to the next quote
      - if the buffer is not empty, append a quote to it
      - append to the buffer the text between the mark and the character before the current position (to strip both quotes)
      - advance one character (past the just read quote)
    - read up to the next comma or newline
    - return the buffer

essentially, split each double quoted segment of the quoted string and then catenate them together with quotes.  thus: `"ABC, ""IJK"" XYZ"` becomes `ABC,` , `IJK`,  `XYZ`, which in turn becomes `ABC, "IJK" XYZ`

Comment: Interesting -- I never thought about this problem in terms of splitting and concatenating.  +1

Answer (score 2):

I would do this using a single character look-ahead, so if you're scanning the string and find a double quote, look at the *next* character to see if it is also a double quote. If it is, then the pair represents a single doublequote character in the output. If it's any other character, you're looking at the end of the quoted string (and hopefully that next character is a comma!). Be sure to account for the end-of-line condition when looking at the next character, too.

Answer (score 1):

A double double-quote (`""`) is a literal double-quote, while a lone double-quote (`"`) is used for enclosing text (including commas).

Here's a regex for a csv field, if that makes things easier:

```
([^",\n][^,\n]*)|"((?:[^"]|"")+)"
```

Group 1 will contain the field if it isn't in quotes, group 2 will contain the field if it is in quotes, minus the surrounding quotes. In that case, just replace all instances of `""` with `"`.

Comment: @Zenikoder No. Think of "" as behaving a lot like \\ does in a string literal. One on its own is a meta character, doubling it says "I just want the literal character".

Comment: For accurate CSV, the regex you've suggested is about right - I'd be tempted to make sure that it was anchored at the start, but that is a minor detail.  You can also get malformed CSV, where you get a 'field' like: `"this part is OK"but this is bogus,`.  You can ignore, reject or accept the extra characters.  What you can't afford to do is treat them as the next field.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: right. To use this you'd want to alternate between matching this anchored at the beginning of the string, and `\s*[\n,]\s*`. If the latter search fails then you have some junk text in your CSV. When it succeeds, group 1 tells you if you're on a new field or a new row.

Comment: I forgot the parens in the regex in my last comment. It should be: `\s*([\n,])\s*`

Answer (score 1):

If you find a double-quote, then you should look for a double-quote in the end of the word/string. If you can't find, then there is an error. The same for a quote.

I suggest you try Flex/Bison in order to write a parser for the CSV file. Both tools will help you to generate a parser and then you can use the C files with the parser and call it from your C++ program.
On Flex, you create a scanner that can find your tokens, like "word" or ""word"". On Bison, you define the syntax.

Comment: Flex is a bit like overkill; Bison is radically overkill.

Comment: @Zenikoder: There's code available online.  Maybe you should get hold of a copy of [The Practice of Programming](http://plan9.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/tpop/) - it is an excellent book! - and download the source code which includes a CSV library.

Comment: I'm sorry but that is not correct unless the content does not have have a comma as you can not identify what the end is.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest reading: [Stop Rolling Your Own CSV Parser](http://secretgeek.net/csv_trouble.asp) and this [CSV RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180). The first is really just someone who wants you to use their C# CSV parser, but still explains many issues.

Your parser should be examining a character at a time. I used a double bool strategy for my [parser in D](https://github.com/he-the-great/JPDLibs/blob/csv/csv/csv.d). Each quote toggles weather the string is quoted or not. When in a quoted Cell you flag when hit a quote, and turn off quoting. If the next character is a quote, quoting is turned on, a quote is added to the result and the flag is turned off. If the next character isn't a quote then the flag is turned off and so is quoting.